# jQuery .ajax blocking .getJSON?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my first question, please be gentle :) I've been trying to resolve this for a couple of hours now and I'm getting nowhere fast.

**Background**

I have a web application where a process is kicked off with .ajax(). This can take a little while to complete, so I have set up a jQuery.progressbar() system to give UI feedback that is started (using setInterval) at the same time as the .ajax(), and every 250ms it calls a .getJSON() to read the progress of the background event. Everything server-side seems to function flawlessly.

**The Problem**

It seems that (from copious use of console.log() that the .ajax() event blocks the .getJSON() from running, until the .ajax() has completed. In my console log I have every 250ms an indication that updateProgressBar() is running, but I never get into the .done portion of it until the original .ajax() call finishes.

What am I missing here?

```
// file copy dialog
$(function () {
    $("#file_copy_dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Copy Files": function () {
                // do ajax copy request
                console.log("Starting setInterval updateProgressBar()");
                window.interval = setInterval('updateProgressBar()', 250);
                console.log("---------------------------------- Firing file_copy AJAX request ---------------------------------");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajax/file_copy.php",
                    data: {
                        job_id: "<?php echo $item_data['job_id']; ?>",
                        item_id: "<?php echo $item_id; ?>",
                        quote_id: "<?php echo $item_data['quote_id']; ?>"
                    }
                })
                    .done(function () {
                    console.log("----------------------------- file_copy AJAX done --------------------------------------");
                });
            },

                "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});

// paste button click event handler
$(function () {
    $("#paste_files").click(function () {

        // open dialog box
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: 0
        });
        $(".progress-label").text("Ready");
        $("#file_copy_dialog").dialog("open");

    });
});

// progress bar initiator
$(function () {
    var progressbar = $("#progressbar"),
        progressLabel = $(".progress-label");

    progressbar.progressbar({
        value: false,
        change: function () {
            progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar("value") + "%");
        },
        complete: function () {
            progressLabel.text("Complete!");
        }
    });
});


// file copy progress checker
function updateProgressBar() {
    console.log("Running updateProgressBar()");
    $.getJSON("/ajax/file_copy_progress.php")
        .done(function (json) {
        console.log("In UpdateProgressBar().done");
        // successful check
        if (json.status == 'ERROR') {
            console.log("updateProgressBar() json.status = ERROR");
            $('#progresstext').text(json.message);
            clearInterval(window.interval);
        } else {
            console.log("updateProgressBar() json.status = " + json.status + " json.value = " + json.value);
            $('#progressbar').progressbar({
                value: json.value
            });
            $('#progresstext').text(json.message);
        }

        if (json.value == 100) {
            console.log("ClearInterval()");
            clearInterval(window.interval);
        }
    })

        .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        // check failed
        $('#progresstext').text("Progress check request failed");
    });
}
```

Forgive my formatting ... and thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Adeneo, turns out there's nothing wrong with the above code at all. The issue lies with PHP locking the session file. Calling session_write_close() and session_start() in strategic places in your initial backend ajax() called' script, will allow the second script to get a look-in occasionally and read the status.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using PHP on the serverside and sessions ?

Comment: Here is a tip. Go to jsfiddle, paste your code in js placeholder and then click "Tidy Up" button. It will format your code `;)`

Comment: adeneo: Hi - Thank you. Yes, the file_copy.php is using an array within $_SESSION['clipboard'] to hold various elements for the progress of the script.

Amit: Thank you ;) The formatting was ok until I pasted on SO and then it went to hell lol

Comment: And that's your issue, PHP locks the access to the session file during the duration of an ajax call to make sure the data isn't corrupted across connections, so you have to use `session_write_close()` to finalize the writing to get a response from the second ajax call.

Comment: adeneo: You're a legend! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies with PHP, not jQuery in this instance.

As pointed out by @adeneo, only one process can read/write the session file at once. (Quite logical when you think about it!). Calling

```
session_write_close()
```

and then

```
session_start()
```

in strategically good places in your initial script, will permit the first script to get a go at reading the session variables occasionally, and make the whole thing work as intended.